# Rails - How to customize process after db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake, database-migration, rake-task

I would like to add some process or at least some log to console after a `rake db:migrate`

My goal for simple is to start `rake diagram:all` request from [railroady](https://github.com/preston/railroady) after each migration to keep my diagrams up-to-date

I guess it's by writing a lib/tasks/db.rake file but as it's linked with database and model I don't want to make a mistake.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: @vzamanillo do I just need to write `Rake::Task['db:migrate'].enhance do
  puts "AFTER"
end` on the db.rake file??

Comment: https://www.dan-manges.com/blog/modifying-rake-tasks

Comment: Thanks I solved with a db.rake file in lib/tasks with following code `Rake::Task['db:migrate'].enhance do
  #my stuff code
end`